# why is one row skipped when including ranges from two sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with some test data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rd8uJp2KTl2ds-s_SWvUSkxNjEscAEiwAO71zSJ2A8Q/edit?usp=sharing.

In the 'All Transactions' sheet, why is row 3 from the 'source data 2' sheet included when I sort by 'category' but not when I sort by 'date'?

Comment: The one with "cat3"? It shows up for me.

Comment: It now shows up because I sorted by 'category'. I'll rephrase the question, as I still don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is there, but it's out of sight because of the blank rows that are included due to the use of whole columns (`A2:B`). Filter the rows where A or B cells are not empty. One way to do that is by using [QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en), i.e.:

```
=QUERY({{'source data 1'!A2:B};{'source data 2'!A2:B}},
"Select Col1,Col2 Where (Col1<>'' OR Col2<>'') Order by Col1",0)
```

Comment: Should it be an AND and not an OR? This assumes that I don't want to include rows that have blanks in either of those columns.

Comment: It´s up to you. In the example formula, using `(Col1<>'' AND Col2<>'')` will exclude those rows where one of the columns has data but the other not, so row 3 and row 5 of `source data 2` will not be include because of the filtering criteria.